# como sacar datos en js que llegan de ajax

Tags: javascript

buenas me gustaría saber como puedo en sacar en un sweetalert los datos que me llegan por ejemplo tengo una función que es cuando hago click ne pregunte si estoy seguro que quiero pagar x numero de factura por como imprimir el numero que llega este es el codigo.

en data recibo

```
array(2) {
  ["monto_pendientep"]=>
  string(9) "RD$ 57200"
  ["numero_facturap"]=>
  string(7) "C000001"
}


    $(document).on('click', '.detalle_pago', function(){
    //toma el valor del id
    var numero_compra = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
          url:"../ajax/consultas_compras.php?op=pagar_compra",
          method:"POST",
          data:{numero_compra:numero_compra},
          cache:false,
          //dataType:"json",
          success:function(data)
          {
        console.log(data);

        Swal.fire({
        title: 'Vas A Pagar La Factura numero?', //quiero que salga el numero_facturap que llega en data
          text: "Monto A Pagar 2000",  //quiero que salga el monto_pendientep que llega en data
          icon: 'question',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'SI',
            cancelButtonText: 'NO'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            Swal.fire(
              'Pagada!',
              'La Factura se pago Correctamente.',
              'success'
            )
          }
        })

          }
        })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya estas obteniendo tu data, y la estas imprimiendo, solo debes usarla como un objeto mas, guardas tu data obtenida en una variable y la muestras en tu sweet alert, eso si, no puedes imprimir el objeto directamente porque te pondra `[Object object]` en el `sweet alert` o almenos eso es lo que sucederia si intentas imprimir un object en el documento, asi que la forma de mostrar tu data es ya sea mostrarla directamente (convertir el objeto en cadena y luego imprimirlo en tu sweet alert).

```
success:function(data)
{
    const dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
    //Ahora muestras el objeto entero en el sweet alert usando `dataString`.
};
```

Si en vez de ello deseas mostrar propiedades en especifico del objeto en el `sweet alert`, entonces solo no lo conviertas, si no que debes usar tu data directamente:

```
success:function(data)
{
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'Vas A Pagar La Factura numero: ' + data.numero_facturap, //quiero que salga el numero_facturap que llega en data
      text: "Monto A Pagar " + data.monto_pendientep,  //quiero que salga el monto_pendientep que llega en data
      icon: 'question',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'SI',
        cancelButtonText: 'NO'
    })
};
```

**Notese que el código no es exactamente el mismo (revisar bien para analizar que ha cambiado).**

Por supuesto esto funcionaria si lo que obtienes desde `ajax` es directamente un `objeto json` y no una cadena de texto.

Si es una cadena de texto lo puedes saber usando `typeof`:

```
console.log(typeof data);
```

Una vez sabiendo que te trae, en el caso de que te traiga una cadena de texto (que no es lo adecuado y deberías especificarle a `jQuery` que te traiga un json directamente).

Lo que deberias hacer, **solo en caso de que la data traida sea una cadena de texto**, es parsearla y usar el objeto parseado:

```
success:function(data)
{
    const dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);
};
```